# I need to return only the names that have more than one franchise

Tags: sql

I need to return only the names that have more than one franchise. I can get a list with everyone and i can get a list of all the names that have more than one but i am unable to have that list show multiple rows with the name in each i only get one row with the name and the count of how many times it is in there. here is the code i have I am using a SQL Server the Xref table look like this

```
fraID|memERBCode|GLLevel|customerNumber|vendorNumber|DAVendorNumber|DAVindoeDisabled|status|di|ctyID
145     145     145         144020145   02PF0145       02DA0145     1                   I   WI   1
146     146     146         144020146   02PF0146       02DA0146     0                   I   3F   1
```

.

```
select [Last Name],[First Name], count(*)
from(
SELECT 
        conLastName as [Last Name], 
        conFirstName as [First Name],
        conMiddleInitial as [Middle Initial],   
        lawsonXRef.memERPCode as [Franchise],
        contactType.ctpDisplayName as [Type],
        contactStatus.ctpDisplayName as [Status]


    FROM Contacts   
    inner join lawsonXRef 
        on lawsonXRef.fraID = Contacts.fraID
    inner join SalesRepresentatives 
        on Contacts.conID = SalesRepresentatives.conID  
    inner join CategoryPopulation contactType
        on contactType.ctpID = Contacts.conTypeId   
    inner join CategoryPopulation contactStatus
        on contactStatus.ctpID = Contacts.conStatusId
    WHERE 
        srActive = 1 -- is Sales Rep.
        and 
            (Contacts.conLastName <> ''     and Contacts.conFirstName <> '')

)data1

    group by [Last Name],[First Name]
        having count(*)>1
    order by [Last Name]
```

Comment: What's your RDBMS (oracle, sql server, mysql, postgres, etc)

Comment: I'm confused as to the output you want... You say you only want to see the "names" that have more than one franchise... the query you have to me would achieve that goal.  Can you give a "sample" output your looking for?  If Jim Bob has 4 franchises and Jane Smith has 7 franchises you should two rows with the above information.  If Jane Doe has 1 franchise, she wouldn't be listed. Are you wanting to see the memerpcode of the franchises along with the contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your contact table will hold multiple records for a single contact - one for each franchise.

If so, the following should work:

```
SELECT  con.conLastName as [Last Name], 
        con.conFirstName as [First Name],
        con.conMiddleInitial as [Middle Initial],   
        lawsonXRef.memERPCode as [Franchise],
        contactType.ctpDisplayName as [Type],
        contactStatus.ctpDisplayName as [Status]
    FROM (select conLastName, conFirstName, conMiddleInitial
          from Contacts
          group by conLastName, conFirstName, conMiddleInitial
          having count(distinct fraID) > 1) con
    inner join Contacts 
        on con.conLastName = Contacts.conLastName and 
           con.conFirstName = Contacts.conFirstName and 
           con.conMiddleInitial = Contacts.conMiddleInitial
    inner join lawsonXRef 
        on lawsonXRef.fraID = Contacts.fraID
    inner join SalesRepresentatives 
        on Contacts.conID = SalesRepresentatives.conID  
    inner join CategoryPopulation contactType
        on contactType.ctpID = Contacts.conTypeId   
    inner join CategoryPopulation contactStatus
        on contactStatus.ctpID = Contacts.conStatusId
    WHERE 
        srActive = 1 -- is Sales Rep.
        and 
            (Contacts.conLastName <> ''     and Contacts.conFirstName <> '')
```

Incidentally, if this is your design then I strongly recommend changing it. What if there are several people called Jane Smith?

Comment: I thought this was working but I still have some names show up with only one entry. but closer than anything i had.

Comment: @user1062034: Probably contacts who have multiple franchises, some of which are with inactive Sales Representatives - if so, you need to decide whether you want to include them (so leave the query as is) or exclude them (amend the `con` subquery to include a link to SalesRepresentatives and a `where srActive = 1` clause).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense i will try and figure out how to do that. This is deeper into SQL than I have had to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at doing something like a derived table in your query that only returns the id of people with multiple franchises.

Guessing at your query, if a Contact exists in lawsonXref more than once, that's considered having muliple franchises. fraID is franchise id and that uniquely identifies a franchise?

```
SELECT 
    conLastName as [Last Name], 
    conFirstName as [First Name],
    conMiddleInitial as [Middle Initial],   
    lawsonXRef.memERPCode as [Franchise],
    contactType.ctpDisplayName as [Type],
    contactStatus.ctpDisplayName as [Status]
FROM
    Contacts   
inner join 
(
    -- this should generate a list of all
    -- the franchise ids that exist more than
    -- once in the xref table
    SELECT 
        X.fraID
    FROM
        lawsonXRef X
    GROUP BY
        X.fraID
    HAVING
        count(1) > 1
    on lawsonXRef.fraID = Contacts.fraID
) AS lawsonXRef
inner join 
    SalesRepresentatives 
    on Contacts.conID = SalesRepresentatives.conID  
inner join 
    CategoryPopulation contactType
    on contactType.ctpID = Contacts.conTypeId   
inner join 
    CategoryPopulation contactStatus
    on contactStatus.ctpID = Contacts.conStatusId
WHERE 
    srActive = 1 -- is Sales Rep.
    and 
    (Contacts.conLastName <> ''
    and Contacts.conFirstName <> '')
```

if that's not working, provide a few rows of LawsonXref data showing an example of a single franchise record and one with multiple.

Comment: I am using SQL Server, the output I need is if Jim Bob has 4 franchises and Jane Smith has 7 franchises  i need Jim Bob listed four times and Jane Smith listed seven times.